# Link a cell to multiple cells exclude middle range in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula

I am new to Google sheet functions, Trying to create **hyperlink from a cell to multiple cells.**

Like

A1 cell in Google sheet should hyperlink to 2 cell range

```
1. B3:F20 
2. I3:L20
```

I can easily hyperlink a cell to given single range Like B3:F20

using this function

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=2&range=B2:F20","Account")
```

But I am struggling to find a solution to make a hyperlink in a cell to more than one range.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
={HYPERLINK("#gid=2&range=B2:F20", "Account");
  HYPERLINK("#gid=2&range=I3:L20", "2ndrange")}
```